# How to move Wiki pages between sites in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

we have created a new site and we want to move our team's wiki to the new site. 
is there a nice and easy way to do it? we've tried the tree view with drag and drop but it won't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after a number of dead ends, I found a quick and easy solution:
Navigate to the physical folder location for your Sharepoint docs.
[Do this by selecting documents in the menu list, select the library tab and then open with explorer]
Once there navigate to the folder containing your wiki site/s. 
They will have a .aspx extension usually
You can then move them to the folder you like.

- Note: The site needs to be checked in or the move process will moan

Answer (score 1):

One of the options could be to save a Wiki site [as a site template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033(v=office.15).aspx). Then deploy it in a site collection and to create new sites from it. But unfortunately since Wiki site is *Publishing based* site, [it is not supported to Save Site as Template](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2492356).

But there is another option - [moving sites via Site Content and Structure](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx#BM5):

> You can move individual list items or entire subsites to another
>   subsite within the site collection. A subsite can be moved to be
>   directly under the top level in the site collection hierarchy or under
>   another subsite in the site collection hierarchy. When you move a
>   subsite, all of the content in the subsite is moved

Steps:

1. Go to `Site Settings`, then `Content and structure (under Site
   Administration)`
2. Select site you would like to move and `Move` action in the context menu
   as shown below on picture [image]
3. In the `Move` dialog select a destination (parent site) and
   then click `OK`  as shown below on picture

   [image]

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try opening both sites/libraries in explorer view, side by side, and copy paste them from one to the other

you can also try to save a template out of the wiki including content and then import it